# Libgdx Can't Load Text Written in Overlap2D

Tags: java, libgdx, freetype, overlap2d

I am attempting to create a game in libgdx using the tool overlap2d, and everything works fine except one key thing: every time I add text to the scene, I get an error stating that it can't find the corresponding font file. I have the file, I've made sure it's spelled right, and I've tried running this with it in my assets folder and just about every other folder in my project, but it just won't work. What do I need to do or where do I need to put this for libgdx to be able to find my font?

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: freetypefonts\Calibri.ttf (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.length(FileHandle.java:602)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator.<init>(FreeTypeFontGenerator.java:90)
at com.uwsoft.editor.renderer.resources.ResourceManager.loadFont(ResourceManager.java:319)
at com.uwsoft.editor.renderer.resources.ResourceManager.loadFonts(ResourceManager.java:312)
at com.uwsoft.editor.renderer.resources.ResourceManager.loadAssets(ResourceManager.java:205)
at com.uwsoft.editor.renderer.resources.ResourceManager.initAllResources(ResourceManager.java:100)
at com.uwsoft.editor.renderer.SceneLoader.<init>(SceneLoader.java:63)
at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:21)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:146)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:123)
```

Comment: can you post the code on how are you loading your font?

Comment: I do not have any code for that. I am just using Overlap2D's loadscene method, and the text is a part of the scene. Should I have some code for loading the font?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the project in editor again, and pressing export again, the ttf file probably did not get exported first time around.